# Не работает оператор switch. Как решить эту проблему?

Tags: java, операторы

```
    do{
        System.out.println("Справка:");
        System.out.println("1. if");
        System.out.println("2. switch");
        System.out.println("3. for");
        System.out.println("4. while");
        System.out.println("5. do-while");
        System.out.println("Выберите: ");

        choice = (char) System.in.read();

        do{
            ignore = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (ignore != '\n');
    } while (choice < '1' | choice > 5);
    System.out.println("\n");
    switch(choice){
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Описание if");
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Описание switch");
            break;
        case '3':
            System.out.println("Описание for");
            break;
        case '4':
            System.out.println("Описание while");
            break;
        case '5':
            System.out.println("Описание do-while");
            break;
    }
}
```

Выдает просто меню справки а при попытке ввести число от одного до пяти ничего не происходит и снова выводит меню. Не понимаю где ошибка.

Comment: >>choice < '1' | choice > 5<< что это такое, и что вы от этого условия ожидаете?

Comment: Это для того, чтобы невозможно было ввести неправильное число, например 10 или -23

Comment: кавычки забыли  `choice > '5'`

Comment: для справки - '1' == 0x31, а 5 == 0x05, Более того, признаться, я удивлён что компилятор явы пропускает применение целочисленной операции | на логических типах...

Comment: Во первых, вы там пользовательский ввод принимаете как char , а он не может быть больше одного символа. Во вторых, вы проверяете `choice < '1'` и это нормально, но потом делаете логический `OR` и проверяете `choice > 5`, будто choice это цифра. Надо так: `choice < '1'  || choice > '5'`

Comment: Всех услышал, спасибо большое.

Comment: @test123 согласно спеке Java - если операнды булевские, то битовые and/or становятся логическими and/or - [раздел 15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в строке:

```
} while (choice < '1' | choice > 5);
```

оператор "|" это побитовое or а не логическое or, необходимо заменить на "||" и
'5' необходимо взять в кавычки, т.к. `'5' != 5`, хотя | и не влияет на результат в данном случае.

В итоге у Вас получается условие:

```
(choice < '1' [true|false])|(choice > 5 [true,false]) =>
[true,false]->[1,0] | [1,0]
1 | 1, 1 | 0, 0 | 1 -> 1 -> true
0 | 0 -> 0 -> false
```

В итоге Ваше условие означает что `choice < 50(('5') | choice > 5`, в итоге получается что второе условие верно всегда, и у Вас `while` всегда `true`